how to get a prediction output sequence of NARX model by MPC
two question:
now there are a NARX model: y(t)=y(y(t-1),y(t-2),u1(t-5),u1(t-6),u2(t-5),u2(t-6)), i have trained my network offline for identifing the plant, and the output of network is prediction output,but just  have one output,not a output sequnce. meanwhile，for the plant, the manipulate variable u=[u1,u2]' , and the plant is a MIMO system.
but in online model predictive control,we need a prediction output sequence to getting the manipulate variable.as described above,the network just has one output in each steps and if i want to get a output sequence,the problem appear to be that I need to provide new inputs to the predictive model each time, and these inputs should be related to the true output of the system and the control variables. But if I haven't even determined the control variables, how can I use them as inputs for the predictive model?.
my codes are as below:
% the prediction model
for i=1:(Np+1)  
        
[NNI_Y,model_Center,model_Width,model_W]=AFNN_NNI(actual_output,UXX,NNI_Center,NNI_Width,NNI_W,NNI_lr,NNI_MaxEpoch);
    NNI_Center = model_Center;
    NNI_Width=model_Width;
    NNI_W=model_W;
    NNI_Y=(outputps.max-outputps.min).*NNI_Y+outputps.min;      
    %UXX(2)=UXX(1);UXX(1)=NNI_Y;UXX(4)=UXX(3);UXX(3)=rand;UXX(6)=UXX(5);UXX(5)=rand;

    y0=[y0;NNI_Y];      % y0:(np+1)*1 initialization of prediction output
end

% calculate MV by casadi
persistent u0;
u0=[10000 1];
u0=repmat(u0, Np, 1);     % u0' control consequence

args.p=2;
args.x0  = [y0;reshape(u0',2*Np,1)];  
sol = solver('x0', args.x0, 'lbx', args.lbx, 'ubx', args.ubx,...
        'lbg', args.lbg, 'ubg', args.ubg,'p',args.p);
u = reshape(full(sol.x((Np+1)+1:end))',2,Np)'; % get controls consequence only from the solution 

u0 = [u(2:size(u,1),:);u(size(u,1),:)];  
u_cl= [u_cl ; u(1,:)];  % store MV of every steps
u0_k = u(1,:)';   % control variance of current step


when i debug,i found the answer geted by solver all is zeros.the codes in sfuntion,so in every sample time it will running
i want control the plant and make the actual output matches the set value as closely as possible
